# JDBC Connection: Not Recconecting after Timeout

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

After some time without using a connection in my application, the next attempt to retrieve a valid connection raises an JDBC exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 81,155,040 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 81,155,040 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

I'd like to know which configuration should I change in order to avoid this issue.

I'm managing the connections in application level through a Hibernate SessionFactory, in ways that the pooling and connection management is totally invisible at this level. Should I have to do some kind of attempting to check and retrieve a brand new connection while dealing with SessionFactory? In time: I'm using Spring too.

Server.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>

  <GlobalNamingResources>

        <Resource auth="Container"
                  description="User database that can be updated and saved" 
                  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
                  name="UserDatabase" 
                  pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
                  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
        />

        <Resource auth="Container" 
                  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                  initialSize="20"                              
                  global="mysql/GestaoProjetos" 
                  maxActive="800" 
                  maxIdle="20" 
                  maxWait="30000" 
                  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="10000" 
                  name="mysql/GestaoProjetos" 
                  password="laranja" 
                  removeAbandoned="true" 
                  removeAbandonedTimeout="300" 
                  testOnBorrow="true" 
                  testWhileIdle="true" 
                  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/GestaoProjetos?autoReconnect=true" 
                  username="tomcat" 
                  validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                  validationInterval="30000"
        />

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

      <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" 
                 port="80" 
                 protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
                 redirectPort="443"
      />

      <Connector port="9" 
                 protocol="AJP/1.3" 
                 redirectPort="443"
      />

      <Engine   defaultHost="localhost" 
                name="Catalina">

                <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
                        resourceName="UserDatabase"
                />

                <Host appBase="webapps" 
                      autoDeploy="true" 
                      name="localhost" 
                      unpackWARs="true" 
                      xmlNamespaceAware="false" 
                      xmlValidation="false">

                        <Context docBase="GestaoProjetos" 
                                 path="/GestaoProjetos" 
                                 reloadable="true" 
                                 source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestaoProjetos"
                                 crossContext="true"
                        />

                </Host>
      </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="SessionFactoryUtil">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USERNAME</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GestaoProjetos?autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <!-- Automatic schema creation (begin) === -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- property name="mappingJarLocations">file:/WEB-INF/lib/</property> --> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Provide the configuration in Spring/Hibernate to retrieve the database connections from your datasource.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, hibernate cfg added. Thanks.

Comment: So you're not using your datasource after all, you're letting Hibernate with the naive and *must not in production* configuration which will manually open a connection every time and that you need to close manually. Looks like you haven't closed the connections, thus your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I've got this feeling in the very momment that I was copying Hibernate's configuration code to the editing question. How can I change Hibernate configuration to use connection pool from Tomcat's Server.xml instead of its own (if possible)?

Comment: You usually integrate Spring and Hibernate. There are several tutorials on the net about it. And they explain how you can use the connection pool from an external datasource.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: could you please suggest me one?

Comment: I just wrote "spring hibernate" and got the official Spring tutorial about it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html It's time for you to enhance your ninja *search-on-the-net* skills :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I only thought that you would have got any experience from a good one. If you can put it in an answer I'm going to accept it. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stays in the error;

> autoReconnect=true

add this parameter end of your connection url.

Comment: This should be a comment